# Symfony 3 dev mode: Error: Maximum function nesting level of '500' reached, aborting

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I really don't know what is wrong just after doing some change in my code then I get the error: `Error: Maximum function nesting level of '500' reached, aborting!` I thaught the problem is just a php configuration but as you can see in the title, after set  the value at 500 even 1000, I still get the same error. notice I'm using Symfony 3.0.1

[image]

Comment: 3 things: 1) Show the code that is causing the problem. You're probably hitting the recursion limit of xdebug because of a problem with the code. 2) Disable xdebug, but you probably have infinite recursion somewhere, and the script will run until you're out of memory. 3) Given that you have xdebug, why not step through the code, and actually _debug_ the problem?

Comment: Edit: the error occur only on dev mode

Comment: Sorry ! I was misusing the framework .... so tired that I lake concentration I just include a controller in twig in a wrong way .... I so sorry !

Answer (score 0):

This is described on this page:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Roughly 30% down the page. Suggests to set your `xdebug.max_nesting_level` setting in the php.ini file.

Not sure if this helps.

Comment: there's more than 1000 nested calls here, every time I've seen this problem, the cause was bad code, not bad config. If the nesting level is 100, then yes, SF debug mode can be a problem. 1000 nested calls though, that suggests, to me at least, that there's something else going on

Comment: Exactly - so please post your code like @EliasVanOotegem has mentioned so that we can help out. At least my suggestion should have been helpful. Without knowing what you do in your code, we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry !! I was so tired that I misuse the framework: Elias Van Ootegem is right I render a controller in a wrong way from twig that is why I've got such an error